# CMake не находит main.cpp

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(objectdetection2)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(OpenCV_DIR “path_to_opencv”)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} “main.cpp” “mainwindow.h” “mainwindow.cpp” “mainwindow.ui”)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
Cannot find source file: "main.cpp" Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M
CMakeLists.txt .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
Failed to compute build system
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, я уже всё перепробовал, не собирается и всё проект!

Comment: Оформи пожалуйста вопрос по-человечески, скрин это плохой вариант, его не скопируешь в ответ, с ним вообще неудобно работать. Это ж не сложно: `Ctrl + C` далее `Ctrl + V` и всё

Comment: Вокруг `main.cpp` и других строк используются **нестандартные кавычки**, которые не интерпритируются CMake-ом как что-то специальное. То, что дело в кавычках, можно увидеть по сообщению об ошибке - кавычки просочились и туда.